# Why is data not being saved in the array? | discord.js v13

Tags: discord.js

Whenever I'm attempting to push data into an array, then log it after the for loop it just prints an empty array. Why is that?

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const db = require('quick.db');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    name: 'XYZ',
    run: async (client, message) => {

        var array_V = ['ID1', 'ID2'];
        var snowflakes = [];
        var i = 0;

        message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
            if (!channel.isText()) return;
            for (const channel of message.guild.channels.cache.values()) {
                let messages = await channel.messages.fetch()
                messages.each((msg) => {
                  if (msg.author.id === array_V[i]) {
                    snowflakes.push(msg.createdTimestamp)
                  }
                })
            }
        });
    }      
}
```

Now outputs `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules` although it is already declared as an async function in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing it in a `.then`. Use `await` and `for` loops to have it update and *then* run the next code

```js
for (const channel of message.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === "GUILD_TEXT").values()) {
  let messages = await channel.messages.fetch()
  messages.each((msg) => {
    if (msg.author.id === array_V[i]) {
      snowflakes.push(msg.createdTimestamp)
    }
  })
}
```

This should work since everything asynchronous is being awaited in the `for` loop

Comment: its giving me this error `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules` although it is an `async` function

Comment: this is the top of the run function in module.exports `run: async (client, message) => {`

Comment: Can you send your current code?

Comment: I've edited it into the post. check it out

Comment: Remove the `.forEach()`

Comment: Doesn't that kind of beat the entire point of the code? to grab each text channel available ? and what would it be replaced with? or will it just be `message.guild.channels`

Comment: update: i've added ur code exactly how it is without that previous `forEach` that you stated to remove, and now getting an `undefined fetch` error

Comment: @lopetox612 I've edited the answer